# send emails using Python's smtplib library,

Tags: python, email, smtp

I am trying to send emails using Python's smtplib library, but the emails are not being delivered. I have checked my SMTP server and port, and they seem to be correct. Here is the code I am using.

```
mport ssl
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
import dblink

dbcursor, conn = dblink.dbconnect()

def send_response(name, receiver_email):
    sender_email = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"
    password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
    subject = "Sent from Python"

    content = f'''
    Test message
    '''

    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(content)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = sender_email
    msg['To'] = receiver_email
     
    context = ssl.create_default_context()

    try:
        with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.att.yahoo.com', 465, context=context) as smtp:
            smtp.login(sender_email, password)
            smtp.send_message(msg)
        print(f"Email sent to {receiver_email}")

        
        qry = "UPDATE student SET response_sent = %s WHERE email = %s"
        vals = (True, receiver_email)
        dbcursor.execute(qry, vals)
        conn.commit()

    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError as e:
        print("SMTP Authentication Error:", e)
    except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
        print("SMTP Exception:", e)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error occurred while sending email: ", e)
```

I have checked the email addresses and passwords, and they all seem to be correct. However, when I run this code, I don't see any error messages, but the emails are not being delivered.
Can someone please help me figure out what I am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!